# how to evaluate this integral:$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{(2x^{2}+1)^2}{e^{-x^2}}dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate this integral  :$\displaystyle{\int_0^1 \frac{2}{(2x^{2}+1)^2}{e^{-x^2}}dx}$ ?

I would be interest for any replies or any comments

Comment: As written, there is a singularity at $x = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, which causes the integral to diverge.

Comment: yes, I edited now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I = 2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-x^{2}} \ dx}{(2x^{2}+1)^{2}}. 
\end{align}
Make the substitution $t = 2 x^{2} + 1$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I = \sqrt{\frac{e}{2}} \int_{1}^{3} \frac{ e^{-t/2} \ dt}{t^{2} \sqrt{t-1}}.
\end{align}
By use of Wolfram Alpha it is seen that
\begin{align}
\int \frac{ e^{-x/2} \ dx}{x^{2} \sqrt{x-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 e}} erf\left( \sqrt{ \frac{x-1}{2} } \right) + \frac{e^{-x/2} \sqrt{x-1}}{x}
\end{align}
where $erf(x)$ is the error function, for which
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{3} \frac{ e^{-x/2} \ dx}{x^{2} \sqrt{x-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 e}} erf(1) + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3 e^{3/2}}.
\end{align}
Now
\begin{align}
I = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}} erf(1) + \frac{1}{3 e}.
\end{align}
It can be stated that the integral in question is:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-x^{2}} \ dx}{(2x^{2}+1)^{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \ erf(1) + \frac{1}{6 e}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to approach this. Let's consider the indefinite integral 
$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int\frac{2e^{-x^2}}{(2x^2+1)^2}dx&=\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x(2x^2+1)^2}dx^2=-\frac12\int\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}d\frac{1}{2x^2+1}= \\
&=-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x(2x^2+1)}+\frac12\int\frac{1}{2x^2+1}d\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}= \\
&=-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x(2x^2+1)}+\frac12\int\frac{1}{2x^2+1}\frac{e^{-x^2}(-2x^2-1)}{x^2}dx= \\
&=-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x(2x^2+1)}+\frac12\int e^{-x^2}d\frac{1}{x}= \\
&=-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x(2x^2+1)}+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}+\int e^{-x^2}dx=\\
&=\frac{xe^{-x^2}}{2x^2+1}+\int e^{-x^2}dx.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$$
It's clear now that
$$\int_0^1\frac{2e^{-x^2}}{(2x^2+1)^2}dx=\frac{1}{3e}+\int_0^1 e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{1}{3e}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\mathrm{Erf}(1).$$
It's also interesting to note that corresponding improper integral has the exact value
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{2e^{-x^2}}{(2x^2+1)^2}dx=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$